# Why does this mathematical operation work? (Getting 8-bit register from 32-bit register)

Tags: assembly

```
E?X % 256 = ?L
```

That always seems to work where 256 is in base 10 and % is the modulus function.

Why?

Comment: The low 8 bits can also be found with `R32 & 255`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"mod 256" is the remainder after division by 256.

In binary, this turns out to be the lowest 8 bits (because 256 is 2 to the 8th).

This is just like "mod 2" gives you the least significant bit (0 or 1).

On (in decimal, base 10), "mod 100" gives you the last two decimals ( 2013 mod 100 => 13).

Answer (score 0):

It's just the way math works.  If you divide a number *x* by *m<sup>n</sup>*, the remainder will be the least significant *n* digits of *x* in base *m*.

For example, in base 10, if you divide any number by 10<sup>*n*</sup>, the remainder of the division will be the least significant *n* digits of your original number.  Examples:

```
     5 mod 10^1 =    5 mod 10  =  5
  1245 mod 10^2 = 1245 mod 100 = 45
```

Exactly the same thing happens in binary - 256 is 2<sup>8</sup> (or 100000000 in binary, if you prefer).  If you divide any number by 100000000 the remainder will be the least significant 8 bits of the that number.

Answer (score 0):

Simple : 
When you take mod by `256` you are actually taking mod by `100000000`

For example : Suppose you have the 32-bit number `11110011111111001111011011110000` and divide it by `256`(base 10) / `100000000` so you are basically taking out the last 8 bits of the number ie `11110000`, you can think of it in this way . In decimal suppose you want a last 4 digits so you have to take mod by `10000` (base 10) . Similar is the case with binary numbers